# Optional parameter in Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, api

I have a API route like,

```
<route url="/V1/product/:productId" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Sample\Api\SampleInterface" method="sample"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

As you can see this route has a required parameter **productId**. Is it possible to **add a optional parameter** to this route?

Something like,

```
<route url="/V1/product/:productId/:optionalParam" method="GET">
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you share if you figured some solution for optional params ?

Comment: @AjwadSyed You can't set optional params in URL directly. You can go with any of the provided 2 solutions.

Comment: From below @Adam solution is for required params and with #NID solution we can not have option to pass optional params while testing from default magento swagger UI, as it only accepts required params

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add parameters without specifying them in your webapi.xml

**etc/webapi.xml**

```xml
<route url="/V1/product/:productId" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Sample\Api\SampleInterface" method="sample"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**Api/SampleInterface.php**

```php
/**
 * Return something.
 *
 * @param string $optionalParam     (optional) additional parameter.
 *     
 * @return string
 */
public function getSomething(int $productId, string $optionalParam = ""): string;
```

**Model/Sample.php**

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSomething(int $productId, string $optionalParam = ""): string
{
    var_dump($productId);
    var_dump($optionalParam);
    
    return "Some return string";
}
```

---

### Example 1:

`https://example.com/rest/V1/product/15`

**Output:**

```
int(15)
string(0) ""
```

### Example 2:

`https://example.com/rest/V1/product/15?optionalParam=some_additional_stuff`

**Output:**

```
int(15)  
string(21) "some_additional_stuff"
```

Comment: Thanks very helping

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but I don't think you can declare a specific parameter as optional from within the xml file, though you can declare your routes in such a way that the parameter becomes optional.
For example if you changed your xml to:

```xml
<route url="/V1/product/:productId" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Sample\Api\SampleInterface" method="sample"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
<route url="/V1/product/:productId/:optionalParam" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Sample\Api\SampleInterface" method="sample"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

So long as the underlying method supports it being optional, something like:

```php
public function sample($productId, $optionalParam = null)
```

This allows the code defined in that method to treat $optionalParam as optional.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass an optional param but not like this `<route url="/V1/product/:productId/:optionalParam" method="GET">`

you can pass it with the endpoint by using a question mark(?)

Suppose your endpoint is this: `http://www.example.com/rest/V1/product/3` and if you want to pass some optional parameter, you can pass it like this:

```
http://www.example.com/rest/V1/product/3?optional_param=8
```

you can retrieve it like this:

```
$optional = $this->_request->getParam('optional_param');
```

Comment: The question is not about calling an endpoint with an optional parameter, but **creating** an endpoint that accepts optional parameters.